# manage redundant dependencies in multiple modules

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, build.gradle

I have read a couples of answers related to my question but those didn't really answer my case.

I have a project structured like this.

Project

- app
- someModule
- moduleA
- moduleB
- moduleC
- ...

moduleA has main features so other modules are pointing to this.

build.gradle(app)

```
implementation project(':moduleA')
implementation project(':moduleB')
implementation project(':moduleC')
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:4.13"
```

build.gradle(moduleA)

```
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:4.13"
```

build.gradle(moduleB)

```
implementation project(':moduleA')
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:4.13"
```

build.gradle(moduleC)

```
implementation project(':moduleA')
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
```

Since same dependencies are in multiple modules, I want to manage common dependencies in one place.

there are some answers saying that change configuration from *implementation* to *api* in build.gradle in parent module (in this case moduleA) but it wouldn't work with my case since I am using different configuration for same dependency as well. (androidTestImplementation and testImplementation for "junit:junit:4.13")